# How to resolve mysql queryAsync (promisify pool) until result will not complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm working with bluebird promises lib

Old code looks like this:

```
var sql1 = this.pool.queryAsync("1.sql").get(0);
var sql2 = this.pool.queryAsync("2.sql").get(0);
var sql3 = this.pool.queryAsync("3.sql").get(0);

return Promise.join(sql1, sql2, sql3, function (sql1Result, sql2Result, sql3Result) {
      //fetching results..
});
```

Now i need cancel to perform queries if result is full.
Roughly speaking:

```
var commonResult = [];

while(commonResult.length < 20) {
 commonResult.push(sqlResult);
}
```

Comment: iirc you can just reject the promise

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`Promise.some`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html)?

Comment: I'm sorry, probably has a value of the item that I did not say: params of every next query dependent on the result of the previous query

Comment: I want to break promise chains when result is full, Promise.some takes int count as second argument. I think that this is not what i need

Comment: It's not clear what `this.pool.queryAsync()` and its `.get()` method return?

Comment: And is there one result or multiple results per query?

Comment: Lucky for you Bluebird 3.0 was released yesterday. So first of all your `.get(0)` calls are no longer required.

Comment: How many do you want to execute at once before testing?